# Precise localization and characterization of rudimentary shapes with neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, computer-vision, object-detection

I understand that there are flavors of (convolutional) neural networks that are useful for object [localization and detection](https://adeshpande3.github.io/adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks-Part-2/) tasks of reasonable difficulty. In all of the examples I have seen so far, localization is formulated as finding the corners of a bounding box. Often, the fit is not required to be very precise:

[image: traffic sign bounding box]

Conversely, I am interested in a task I want to achieve very precise localization and characterization of some simple shapes or objects. As an example of one of the simplest cases I can think of, my inputs will be images like the following:

[image: 28 21 15]

Given this 60x60 image, I want my neural net(s), via **regression**, to tell me that the circle's **diameter is 18px** and its **centre is located at (28, 21)** from top left. (I will train it using similar 60x60 images with white circles of various sizes on black backgrounds.)

Later I am interested in dealing with similar tasks in the real world, e.g. spheres/cubes/cylinders with different viewing angles, light conditions, occlusions, etc. However, I am interested in solving this simplest case first, chiefly because I can generate data for this very easily.

I have the following specific questions:

1. Have neural nets been successfully applied to such tasks before? (e.g. precisely determining sizes and centroids of objects)
2. My understanding is that these things are at least theoretically possible using convolutional nets, or even sufficiently complicated vanilla fully connected nets. Is this correct?
3. What architecture(s) would be appropriate for these tasks?

Note: I am aware that fitting a bounding box to the circles and calculating its centre and size will solve this particular case, but it will not generalize to handle occlusions, changing lights, etc. I would like to move towards a method which can, for example, calculate the centroids and diameters of spheres in real-world B&W photos.

Note 2: I have experimented with this task using both fully connected and simple convolutional nets that I built using [Keras](https://keras.io/), without much success. Hence I would like to get comments/advice about the theoretical possibility and appropriate architecture(s).

Comment: 1. This has definitely been done in the past (e.g. number plates). 2. A fully connected net can map any function, but convolutional nets are more effective. 3. Convolutional nets. I'm not an expert, but just some short info :)

Comment: Your simple b&w cases should be pretty simple to solve with keras.  You mention you tried but didn't have much luck.  Two possible issues, did you normalize the greyscale pixel values to 0-1.0 , and did you normalize the coordinates/radius? Essentially just divide them by 60 (or max pixel dimension) The other possible gotcha is that when you use real images -- as opposed to a built in getData() function, e.g. mnist) they come in as m x n x 3  or ( m x n x 1) and they need to reordered as numpy arrays such that they are 3 x m x n,  (or 1 x m x n)

Comment: ConvNets operate naturally on 3rd rank tensors, so you can output pixel-wise prediction for many classes. Your example is straightforward, with only 2 classes. See for example https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf for general idea how it is applied. From such output computing centroid is trivial

Comment: @photox - Thanks for the tips. I did get some decent results when I normalized the images and the labels.